# How to build a "word-by-word" autocomplete in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I already did some research and ended up with several autocomplete boxes which have one thing in common: they all match the whole expression which has been entered. Sometimes, they seem to be easily expandable, but at the end, they aren't.

However, I need a Textbox which allows the user to enter a word (e.g. "tag1"), displays a popup with some suggestions **based on this single word**, accept the suggestion with the return key and type in a new word (e.g "tag1 tag2") in the same textbox, with the popup popping up again. (I like the way CintaNotes handles this)

I need this for a tagging interface. It's often faster for the user to write the tags into a simple box, but sometimes, he needs assistance. This is what the autocomplete is for.

I've found some results, which don't work for my purpose (imho):

- http://www.wpfpedia.com/item/details/743/wpf-autocomplete-textbox-control
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Autocomplete.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/autocomplete_textbox.aspx
- http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2011/01/autocomplete-textbox-with-wpf.html

Btw, **I really like the way** the Tag-Box for SO operates.

Does anyone have an idea? Is there a "out-of-the-box" - solution somewhere, which suits my needs but I didn't find? Or do I have to build one myself?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution? A few years I implemented a popup autocomplete in WPF modeled on the autocomplete in Visual Studio. The autocomplete dialog was a subclass of Popup. It worked together with color coding in a RichTextBox. Tokenizing the text in a RichTextBox is doable, and with just a few hints you could probably recreate my work. If you still need something, I could probably dig up the code.

Comment: @Rethunk: if you're still able to dig up the code, then I'd love to see it

Comment: Ties: I'm going to be away from my computer for a few weeks, but can try to find the code when I get back.

Comment: @Rethunk I'd be interested in seeing your implementation as well.

Comment: @ihake: Sorry, I've been swamped with work the past few months and haven't taken the time to dig up my old code. I hope to have the chance to do so soon. When I have the code I'll add a new comment here.

Comment: @ihake: I found the original code for my WPF autocomplete editor, but it's tied in with a bunch of proprietary stuff, unfortunately. That said, if you could describe a few problems you wanted to solve, I could probably pare the code down to some usable form.

Comment: @Rethunk thanks for your response! My application has a section where users enter expressions in a text box using operators and keywords. (I'm using http://flee.codeplex.com to do this, btw.) I was hoping to find something that would allow me to hand a list of keywords (as strings) to the text box and give the users some kind of auto-complete feature so that he or she doesn't have to remember all the variable names when writing expressions in the text box. If you feel like throwing something together from what you have, that would be awesome, but I certainly understand if you don't! :)

Comment: @Rethunk I'd jump into ihake's request, because I'm still interested in a solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean a textbox which autocomplete for multiple words.
Like TokenizedTexbox on WPF Extended Toolkit.
this is the page: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TokenizedTextBox&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried the TokenizedTextbox, it seemed pretty good, but was still missing the autocomplete-popup. Maybe I will put some customisation into this.

Comment: You could implement it, in that page you can access the source code

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would need to create your own **[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)** object of **Key** and **Value** pairs and hook that Dictionary to the textbox events and popup a suggestions dialog that displays the **Value(s)** from your **Dictionary**

Comment: Yeah, somehow...I guess I'll try to build a UC this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Check this implementation out: http://code.google.com/p/kocontrols/downloads/list
You may inject your own Search algorithm and your own converter which converts the selected element to text, which you display in the TextBox. You will have to modify it slightly but I think that you might be able to solve your problem by basing your control on this implementation.
I never thought about this type of use case. 
Can't you use different textboxes for the different tags? Something similar to how goole code does it?

Comment: This looks like any other autocomplete box to me? I.e. it doesn't support multiple words without some hacking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have time, you can use the RichEditControl or TextBox and apply the same pattern used in Intellisense engine or Code Completation enabled editors: Hook the text changes events, Recogize context (last/current word) and display the options list on popup control. And optionally, on commit (detect acceptation or space key), apply the format to the word.