# C# - Using autocomplete on more than just a word

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

I'm trying to use autocomplete to a textbox for more than just a word, but I didn't find anything on the internet. Is there any way to achieve this on windows forms? The autocomplete will end once a word will be written and it'll begin again on space.

[image]

Comment: Apparently it's just a matter of supplying phrases instead of words as the autocomplete data source.   See https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/autocomplete-textbox-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Dupplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932075/is-there-any-way-to-use-autocomplete-with-multiple-words-inside-the-textbox-in-a & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100945/how-to-build-a-word-by-word-autocomplete-in-wpf

Comment: Also: https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c%23/